# Is there a way of foreaching an Iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

Java now has a convenient way to foreach a Collection eg.

```
for (MyClass c : aCollection) {
...
}
```

Is there something similarly elegant to foreach an Iterator or am I stuck with :

```
for (;it.hasNext();) {
   MyClass c = it.next();
   ...
}
```

Update : for people who find this a strange question, I'm used to Python where

```
for x in xs :
  f(x)
```

works whether xs is a collection OR an iterator (or even a generator). I was kind of caught out and surprised that Java didn't work like this.

I'm implementing a library where I'm returning iterators to some internal collections rather than the collections themselves. But I'm now concerned that this will force the users of my library back to using an older / uglier way of traversing than the foreach. Does this effectively deprecate iterators if people are used to using the foreach construct?

Comment: Don't you mean while (it. hasNext())

Comment: I'd use a while() loop, but this is pretty much how it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apart from arrays which are a peculiar beast, the "extended for" loop you use here is just a result of the class implementing `Iterable`. And this interface only provides one method which is [to return an... `Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--).

Which means that if you write in code:

```
for (final Foo foo: someInstanceImplementingIterableOfFoo) {
    doSomethingWith(foo);
}
```

it is in fact equivalent to:

```
final Iterator<Foo> iterator = someInstanceImplementingIterableOfFoo.iterator();

Foo foo;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    foo = iterator.next();
    doSomethingWith(foo);
}
```

So, the answer really is no, no elegant way...

That is, unless you use Java 8. It has added [`forEachRemaining()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) on `Iterator`.

Or just create a utility class:

```
public final class IteratorWrap<T>
    implements Iterable<T>
{
    private final Iterator<T> iterator;

    public static <X> IteratorWrap<X> wrap(final Iterator<X> iterator)
    {
        return new IteratorWrap<>(iterator);
    }

    private IteratorWrap(final Iterator<T> iterator)
    {
        this.iterator = Objects.requireNonNull(iterator);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return iterator;
    }
}
```

In code you'd then just:

```
for (final Foo foo: IteratorWrap.wrap(iteratorOfX))
    doSomethingWith(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you want something modern, using Java 8 you can do

```
Iterator<String> names = Arrays.asList("one","two","three").iterator();
for(String name : (Iterable<String>) () -> names) {
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

Since the for-loop expects an Iterable Object, with this technique you can provide an `Iterable` out of an `Iterator` by using a lambda expression.

As mentioned by fge in another answer, though, this is equivalent to the following Java 8 expression using method references and avoiding the creation of the Iterable:

```
names.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

So, you can pack your logic into a `Consumer` and solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java's "enhanced" `for` loop requires that the target to be iterated must implement `Iterable`.  But if you have only an `Iterator`, which doesn't implement `Iterable`, there is no built-in way of using the `Iterator` as the target of a foreach loop in Java.

If you can't use Java 8, you can create an adapter class that wraps the `Iterator`, implements `Iterable`, and returns the wrapped iterator in the `iterator()` method.

```
class IterableIterator<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
   private Iterator<T> iterator;

   public IterableIterator(Iterator<T> iterator)
   {
      this.iterator = iterator;
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<T> iterator()
   {
      return iterator;
   }
}
```

Then, if you have an `Iterator`, you can use it like this:

```
Iterator<MyClass> itr = getIteratorSomehow();
for (MyClass obj : new IterableIterator<MyClass>(itr))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Iterator<String> names = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three").iterator();
    String foo;
    while((foo= Iterators.getNext(names, null))!=null){
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I just googled... I feel like I've done this before without the noelementexception... Do you know what I could be thinking?

Comment: Well, nothing guarantees that 1. the iterator you have can produce null values at all, and 2. that even if it can, such a value means "end of the iterator"; `Iterator` does not have `.hasNext()` for no reason :p